# can anyone explain dfp line item in headerbidding concept?

Tags: prebid.js, header-bidding

I am new to header bidding. In header bidding concept, what is dfp line item?
is it for Double click? If any one know please share.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is for Double Click ([DFP](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/82236?hl=en)). However, it would do for any other ad server providing similar functionality.

Here is a guide on step-by-step DFP setup for `prebid.js`
http://prebid.org/adops/step-by-step.html

Answer (score 0):

Its important to understand what Prebid is actually trying to do here between the prebid auction and ad server starting its auction.

DFP is the "usual" ad server that people use but as @user9207697 said it could be anything (and even technically no ad server)

In a DFP setup, the API call [pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync()](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/publisher-api-reference.html#module_pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync) is called to set key values on the ad units. This then corresponds to line items with each of the possible prices returned so that its then included in the AdServer auction.

If it wins the adServer auction, [pbjs.renderAd](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/publisher-api-reference.html#module_pbjs.renderAd) is called to tell prebid to render the wining ad creative (it won in both the Prebid and DFP auctions)

In theory you could just call `renderAd` after the prebid auction to fire off the winning creative (but then you lose out on the benefits of the ad server). Key values are what enable the ad servers to know what Prebid did on page.